# What is the quality of the rafting on the Nile at a Jinja after the damming of Bujagali Falls

Tags: activities, water-sports, uganda, waterfalls, rivers

I have found [a company offering Grade 5 Rafting](http://raftafrica.com/) on the Nile near Jinja Uganda. They make no mention of the fact the Bujagali Falls have been dammed and what if any effect this has had on the quality of the rapids.

The Damming occurred in 2011, and there is no last updated link on their page. So I am after some independent information on the status and class of rapids available.

Comment: Did they really condemn these falls to hell? You probably meant the other damming (to create a dam), but my edits were rejected as too minor.

Comment: seems to be fixed now, funny I never right dam only ever damn.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Nile post the Bujagali dam:

Since the completion of the Bujagali dam the rafting has moved downstream. Bujagali Falls itself and a few surrounding rapids were lost to the reservoir but the rafts now start at Overtime and now continue all the way to the Hairy Lemon island. This is around 25kms. Previously this section was done as part of a two day trip.

The Nile is still regarded by many as one of the best big volume destinations in the world for rafting and kayaking. In terms of what is left, everything below Silverback is still there and running well. So to summarise; you’ve got the following (with rafting grades in brackets):

- Overtime (5)/Dead Dutchman (6),
- Fairytale (4)/Chop Suey (4)/Retrospect (3),
- Bubugo (3),
- Superhole (3),
- Itanda (5)/Hypoxia (6)/Kalagala (6),
- Vengence (4)/Novacaine (5),
- Hair of the Dog (4),
- Kula Shaker (3),
- Nile Special (4),
- Malalu (3) 
  And plenty of other smaller rapids and different channels that are unnamed.

For recent videos and photos of rafting and kayaking check out:

- Nile River Explorer's Facebook page and Vimeo (http://vimeo.com/user19727493)
- Kayak the Nile's Facebook page and YouTube channel (http://www.youtube.com/user/KayaktheNileUganda)